# Why openCV is "blocking" my python script?

Tags: python, macos, opencv, visual-studio-code, virtualenv

so I am still new to python and I tried to use a script that create bokeh effect on an image written by someone else. Here is the repository : [Bokeh-Effect-in-Image-using-Python](https://github.com/Pushkar-Singh-14/Bokeh-Effect-in-Image-using-Python)

Here is more information about how the code works from the author: [bokeh-effect-in-image-using-python](https://py2py.com/bokeh-effect-in-image-using-python/)

Notice that I am coding on VSCode, macOS BigSur, Python 3.9.

First I created a folder for my project then I created a virtual environment, it has been recognised by VsCode and incorporated into the project (so I have the .vscode folder with the json file), I created a python file in which I pasted the code and I downloaded the packages I needed inside the virtual environment.

I also tried to add different lines in the json file based on what I read on the web but it doesn't work.

The problem is that the code runs until it encounters lines using `OpenCV` package, I don't have any Traceback but the code just do nothing.
Here is what I have in the terminal.
[Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkGP5.png)

I tried to use print at different places and to remove certain lines which use opencv and the problem occurred each time `opencv` was used or when `Tracker_HSV` was used (if I deleted all the lines using opencv before) but I think it is because `Tracker_HSV` use `OpenCV`.

So maybe I made a mistake during the setup of the project or `opencv` is not working correctly, I don't know what to do.
(Sorry for my English, I am French.)

Comment: Could you please provide us with minimized reproduction of the problem you described? Please describe in detail the problem you encountered.

Comment: I think I already described it entirely, according to the different tests I made, lines of code seem to “block my code”, the script just do nothing when it encounters a line which use opencv package, but it does not stop.

Comment: You need to be specific on which lines of code "block" your script, as people are asking for details, you need to provide them, not self-declare that you described it correct. It is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

According to the information you provided, for the use of the module "`opencv`", it is recommended that you try the following:

1. Please install the module "[opencv](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/)" correctly: "`pip install opencv-python`"
2. Please use the absolute path of the picture in the code here: "`img = cv.imread("D:/.../Bokeh_Demo/flower.jpg")`"
3. When importing the module "`cv2`", because it contains other files named "cv2", (so pylint reported some errors here, but this does not affect the execution of the code). We can use "`from cv2 import cv2 as cv`" to distinguish them.

Run:

[image]

[image]

Update 1：

Please check that the module "`opencv`" has been successfully installed in your currently selected VSCode environment：

[image]

More reference: [Environment in VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments).

Update 2:

> ```
> # import cv2
> from cv2 import cv2 as cv 
>
> import numpy as np
> import Tracker_HSV as tr
> from PIL import Image
> import os
>
> # cv2.namedWindow('mask', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
> cv.namedWindow('mask',cv.WINDOW_NORMAL)
>
> cv.resizeWindow('mask',(500,500))
> filename= 'flower.jpg'
> cwd = os.getcwd()
> name_file=os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
>
> path_save_temp=os.path.join(cwd,'Data')
> path_save_folder=os.path.join(path_save_temp,f'{name_file}_blur_data')
> if not os.path.exists(path_save_folder):
>     os.makedirs(path_save_folder)
>
>
> img = cv.imread("D:/....../test_Bokeh/Bokeh_Demo/flower.jpg")
> blur = cv.GaussianBlur(img,(5,5),0)
> img_hsv=cv.cvtColor(img,cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
>
> file_save_blur= os.path.join(path_save_folder,'blur.png')
> im_blur = cv.GaussianBlur(img,(81,81),0)
> cv.imwrite(file_save_blur,im_blur)
>
> xs,ys,w,h = cv.selectROI('mask',img)
> crop_img=crop_img_true=crop_img_contour=img[ys:ys+h, xs:xs+w]
>
> if not crop_img_true.shape[0]> 1:
>     crop_img_true=img
>
> x,y,z,a,b,c=(tr.tracker(crop_img_true))
>
> crop_img_true=cv.cvtColor(crop_img_true,cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
>
> file_save_mask_inrange= os.path.join(path_save_folder,'mask inRange.png')
> mask_inRange=cv.inRange(crop_img_true,(x,y,z),(a,b,c))
> cv.imwrite(file_save_mask_inrange,mask_inRange)
>
>
> _, threshold = cv.threshold(mask_inRange, 250, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY)
> Gauss_threshold =cv.adaptiveThreshold(threshold,255,cv.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,cv.THRESH_BINARY_INV,101,10)
>
>
> blank_space_black= np.zeros((crop_img_true.shape[0],crop_img_true.shape[1]),np.uint8)
> blank_space_black[:]=(0)
>
> _,contours,_ = cv.findContours(Gauss_threshold, cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
>
>
> maxi=cv.contourArea(contours[0])
> c=[]
>
> for cnt in contours:
>     if cv.contourArea(cnt)>=maxi:
>         maxi=cv.contourArea(cnt)
> ##        print(cv2.contourArea(cnt))
>         c= cnt
>
> file_save_contour= os.path.join(path_save_folder,'Contour.png')
> cv.drawContours(crop_img_contour, c, -1, (0, 255, 0), 5)
> cv.imwrite(file_save_contour,crop_img_contour)
>
>
> file_save_poly= os.path.join(path_save_folder,'mask fill poly.png')
> mask_poly=cv.fillConvexPoly(blank_space_black,c,(255,255,255))
> cv.imwrite(file_save_poly,mask_poly)
>
> crop_img_true=cv.cvtColor(crop_img_true,cv.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
>
> file_save_mask_bitwise= os.path.join(path_save_folder,'mask bitwise and.png')
> mask_bitwise_and = cv.bitwise_and(crop_img_true,crop_img_true,mask=mask_poly)
> cv.imwrite(file_save_mask_bitwise,mask_bitwise_and)
>
> im2= Image.open(file_save_mask_bitwise)
> im2=im2.convert('RGBA')
>
> datas=im2.getdata()
> newdata=[]
>
> for data in datas:
>     if data[0]== 0 and data[1]== 0 and data[2]== 0:
>         newdata.append((255,255,255,0))
>     else:
>         newdata.append(data)
>
> file_save_transparent= os.path.join(path_save_folder,'transparent.png')
> im2.putdata(newdata)
> im2.save(file_save_transparent)
>
> im_blur= Image.open(file_save_blur)
>
> file_save_final= os.path.join(path_save_folder,'final.png')
> im_blur.paste(im2,(xs,ys),im2)
> im_blur.save(file_save_final)
>
> im_final= Image.open(file_save_final)
> im_final.show('Final Result')
>
> cv.imshow('GaussianBlur',blur)
>
> cv.waitKey(0)
> cv.destroyAllWindows()
> ```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I tried what you said but it doesn't work. I tried to use the debugger to see where it "stops" and the program do not continue after the first line "cv.namedWindow('mask',cv.WINDOW_NORMAL)". Maybe cv2 is "blocked" on macOS Big Sur ??

Comment: @ Mattéo Menager -Please check that the module "opencv" has been successfully installed in your currently selected VSCode environment, I have updated my answer and you can refer to it.

Comment: Yes I tried and it is installed, I have exactly the same output as you.

Comment: @Mattéo Menager -Have you tried using other [python interpreters](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments)? And what happens after reloading VSCode?

Comment: Yes I already tried and still the same problem.

Comment: @Mattéo Menager -Does the code still stop at "_cv.namedWindow('mask',cv.WINDOW_NORMAL)_"? Is there a file "flower.jpg" in your current project that can be opened?

Comment: @Mattéo Menager -When debugging the code, does the terminal and "DEBUG CONSOLE" display any information?

Comment: Yes the program acts the way I described it, the cv2 lines blocks the script, it does not exit or throw errors but just do nothing. I gave you the link of the repo to see the code but I changed the name of the file with the path of a file I have to execut it.

Comment: @Mattéo Menager - Yes, I also used the code you provided in the question, and I modified the path of the picture in the code. (I updated the complete code I used and you can refer to it.)  In addition, how do you run the code? (The green execute button or use the execute command?)

Comment: It doesn’t work but thanks for your help. I type python3 bokeh.py (i called my file this way) or python3 bokeh.py to run my code. Do you think the problem can be caused by macOS ?

Comment: @Mattéo Menager -Please try to run the code by clicking the green execute button at the top right in VSCode.

Comment: I already tried but it does not change anything.

Comment: Please describe in detail the current running status of your code and the content displayed on the terminal.

Comment: I can’t it just do nothing, I don’t have any errors just the “typing white box”